# Postman test - validating value in array

Tags: arrays, validation, testing, duplicates, postman

I have a test in Postman where I can validate a value in an array. The problem I run into is which the value is returned can be random.
This is what the json looks like that I'm validating.

```
[
    {
        "id": "7776",
        "revision": {
            "revisionId": "7780",
            "createdByUserId": "Lakare12",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-07-29T16:49:34.000+05:30"
        },
        "identifiers": [
            {
                "system": "urn:oid:1.2.752.129.2.1.4.1",
                "value": "CDE473Child1",
                "use": "primary",
                "displayValue": null
            }
        ],
        "name": "AA Child 01",
        "active": true,
        "hasChildren": false,
        "parentUnitId": "7768"
    },
    {
        "id": "7783",
        "revision": {
            "revisionId": "7783",
            "createdByUserId": "Lakare12",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-07-30T08:47:40.000+05:30"
        },
        "identifiers": [
            {
                "system": "urn:oid:1.2.752.129.2.1.4.1",
                "value": "CDE473Child3",
                "use": "primary",
                "displayValue": null
            }
        ],
        "name": "BB main Child 03",
        "active": true,
        "hasChildren": false,
        "parentUnitId": "7768"
    }
]
```

I need to test that name contains `BB main Child 03`

Comment: Please format the JSON block in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and check for name in each array element.